# Crystal Crosstab Embedded Summaries in V11?

Tags: crystal-reports, formula, crosstab

I can't believe I am having such difficulty finding the answer to what I believe is a simple question.

I have a crosstab report which has

```
 Pivot        ColA         ColB
PivotC1     <cellA1>     <cellB1>
PivotC2     <cellA2>     <cellB2>
PivotC3     <cellA3>     <cellB3>
```

All I want to do is add a column, that does a row-wise formula in the crosstab. That's it! For example on the first row, a new cell would be to the right which has the formula `0.5*(A1+B1/A1)`. The content of the formula will be a couple different things but it really only needs to support basic cell references and arithmetic.

I found "Embedded Summary" functionality which does almost exactly what I want, but when I right click for the context menu on a crosstab in my version of Crystal (V11.0) I see nothing of the sort. Furthermore there are some relevant functions named in other references (such as [here](http://www.crystalkeen.com/articles/crystalreports/crosstabsummaryfunctions.htm)) that use "GridValueAt" which makes perfect sense... but once again, if I try to use that in a formula, it doesn't recognize the function.

Specifically the Crystal 2008 documentation says to use an Embedded summary you right click on the crosstab and choose "advanced calculations" then "embedded summary".. I dont see either of those options.

Am I missing a library? Was the functionality rebranded in V11?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using 2008, you right click on a field in the crosstab to see embedded summary functionality. But I don't think that's what you need based on your explanation. I think you would be more successful using a calculated member. Right click the top left of your crosstab and select advanced calculation then select calculated member.

Comment: I dont see "Advanced Calculation" when I perform that rightclick. Is there some kind of "advanced" mode I need to turn on ?

Comment: I see the problem. I was thinking Crystal XI was a later version than 2008, but it is not - so I do not have access to this functionality because Crystal is too old.

Comment: depending upon your environment.... 2008 is an upgrade worth the money if you use CR much... IMHO

Answer (score 2):

I know this is an old question, but in case anyone else comes across this:

Using the GridValueAt function, you can reference the cells within the crosstab. For example -

GridValueAt (CurrentRowIndex, CurrentColumnIndex ,1 ) / 
GridValueAt (CurrentRowIndex, CurrentColumnIndex ,2 )

gives you A1/B1

Hope this helps.

Comment: Hah, sorry, I posted too quick. Looks like you tried that already.